# How can I deploy microservices with angular in front part and flask in back part with docker?

Tags: angular, docker, flask, docker-compose, microservices

I am trying to deploy an aplication with microservices architecture in docker. I have the back part deploy, but I am not able to deploy the front part. In each microservice, I have a dockerfile and a docker-compose for deploy all the services.

The dockerfile for angular part is:

```
FROM node:8.10.0-alpine as builder

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN npm install && \
    npm install -g @angular/cli

RUN echo $(node -v)
RUN echo $(ng version)
RUN echo $(npm -v)

RUN npm rebuild node-sass

RUN ng build

RUN echo $(ls -l)

FROM nginx:1.15.8-alpine

EXPOSE 4200

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist/* /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

and in the docker-compose for this part:

```
  client:
    build:
      context: ./Front_VegApp/VegWebFuse
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    volumes:
      - './Front_VegApp/VegWebFuse:/usr/src/app'
      - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - 4200:4200
    depends_on:
      - users
      - foods
      - shops
```

All works fine, but when I try to access to localhost:4200/ the server dont response.

It is the first time that I deploy a front part in nginx, normally i use apache, what I dont know if It is better or not.
Other question is which is going to be the url for the back, I mean, in angular all the services attack to an url depending on the service, but with this methodology I am not sure which is going to be the url.

Thanks in advance.